# Exchange Management Shell cmdlet not found

Tags: powershell, exchange

I just recently installed an Exchange 2019 environment as we are planning to migrate from IBM Domino to Microsoft Exchange.

Ever since creating a Database Availability Group some menu items are missing in the Exchange Control Panel and sometimes there are errors in the windows event log. I wanted to take a closer look at this but unfortunately it seems like my exchange management shell is not working as expected:

Some Exchange specific powershell command are working just fine but others do not.

Any idea where this could come from?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem.
The user I use to log onto the ECP and run the Management Shell was lacking permissions.
I added that User to the following Active Directory groups and after that I was able to see all menu items in the ECP again and all Management Shell commands would work again:

- Compliance Management
- Organization Management
- Records Management